# With the Bash shell on OS x is it possible to write a script that will let me mount OneDrive to the desktop?

Tags: bash, shell, onedrive

I would like to be able to mount my OneDrive account to the desktop.  Then use rsync to synchronize it with a local folder.  I know how to use rsync but need someone to point me in the right direction for mounting OneDrive.

I have been able to sync folders PC to Mac by mounting the PC shared folder onto the Mac then using rsync to synchronize.

No code yet to connect to OneDrive.

To be able to mount OneDrive to the Mac desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mount a remote "drive" to OneDrive as the synchronization/authentication protocol is not implemented within the OS X file system.

(Answer from mac stackexchange [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/218844/how-can-i-mount-microsoft-onedrive-as-a-network-drive-in-osx))

Some proprietary software handles this and can help, or you could write your own.